# Rspec - nameError: undefined local variable or method `sammiches_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am a bit confused here. I am trying to do TDD and have run into an issue. Rspec is telling me the following-

```
1) Sammiches GET /sammiches display some sammiches
 Failure/Error: visit sammiches_path
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `sammiches_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_4::Nested_1:0x007fa7afcfed70>
 # ./spec/requests/sammiches_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Sammiches GET /sammiches creates a new sammich
 Failure/Error: visit sammiches_path
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `sammiches_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_4::Nested_1:0x007fa7ae11e6f0>
 # ./spec/requests/sammiches_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is what my spec file looks like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Sammiches" do
describe "GET /sammiches" do
it "display some sammiches" do
    @sammich = Sammich.create :name => 'bacon'
    visit sammiches_path
    page.should have_content 'bacon'
end

it "creates a new sammich" do
    visit sammiches_path
    fill_in 'Sammich', :with => 'lechuga'
    click_button 'add Sammich'

    current_path.should = root_path
    page.should have_content 'lechuga'

    save_and_open_page
end
end
end
```

My routes are -

```
 sammiches_index GET    /sammiches/index(.:format)    sammiches#index
  Sammiches GET    /Sammiches(.:format)          Sammiches#index
            POST   /Sammiches(.:format)          Sammiches#create
 new_Sammich GET    /Sammiches/new(.:format)      Sammiches#new
 edit_Sammich GET    /Sammiches/:id/edit(.:format) Sammiches#edit
    Sammich GET    /Sammiches/:id(.:format)      Sammiches#show
            PUT    /Sammiches/:id(.:format)      Sammiches#update
            DELETE /Sammiches/:id(.:format)      Sammiches#destroy
       root        /                             Sammiches#index
```

Routes-

```
Sammiches::Application.routes.draw do
get "Sammiches/index"

resources :sammiches
 root :to => 'Sammiches#index'
```

New Error-

```
1) Sammiches GET /sammiches creates a new sammich
 Failure/Error: visit sammiches_path
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `sammich' for #<Sammich:0x007fd0007d2f80>
 # ./app/views/sammiches/index.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_sammiches_index_html_erb___2703584807867277870_70265660050820'
 # ./app/views/sammiches/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_sammiches_index_html_erb___2703584807867277870_70265660050820'
 # ./spec/requests/sammiches_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Sammiches GET /sammiches display some sammiches
 Failure/Error: visit sammiches_path
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `sammich' for #<Sammich:0x007fd00006f4f0>
 # ./app/views/sammiches/index.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_sammiches_index_html_erb___2703584807867277870_70265660050820'
 # ./app/views/sammiches/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_sammiches_index_html_erb___2703584807867277870_70265660050820'
 # ./spec/requests/sammiches_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am at a bit of a loss here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: At first glance, you may have a capitalization mismatch for `Sammich`; what are the contents of your routes.rb file?

Comment: Added my routes file. I changed the resource capitalization, but now I get a new error... Thanks!

Comment: Your new error is on line 4 of app/views/sammiches/index.html.erb. You're trying to use a variable/method `sammich` that hasn't been defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have added `resources :Sammiches` in `config/routes.rb`.

Change it to `resources :sammiches`. Sticking to the convention, helps. :)

Your route file should look like:

```
Sammiches::Application.routes.draw do

resources :sammiches
 root :to => 'sammiches#index'
```

Comment: Good eye! Thanks! I fixed that but now I get... Sammiches GET /sammiches display some sammiches
     Failure/Error: visit sammiches_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `sammich' for #<Sammich:0x007fd42f044ad8>

Comment: Added some details on my post above. This is how your route.rb should look like.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I am getting a new error, so I guess that is progress! I added it to the bottom of my original post. Thanks again.

Comment: Your path is correctly setup now. You have error at your view side logic. You are probably using .sammich somewhere in wrong way.